# Intercepting RegisterClass method in Classes.pas Delphi7

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Is there a way of doing that? The list of registered classes is in the TRegGroups instance in Classes.pas unit, but problem is that instance is declared in the implementation section of unit. Is there a way of obtaining an address of RegisterClass procedure, or RegGroups.RegisterClass method?

Comment: `RegisterClass` is declared in the interface section. So, yes, you can take the address of the function. How about telling us what you **really** want to do. This smells like an XY question.

Comment: I have a large number of classes in statically linked packages. When I start application it hangs for quite some time (I guess until it registers them all), so I'd like to have some kind of progress status (Splash Screen with a label), but I would't want to change all the places where the RegisterClass is called. I'd prefer to "intercept" the RegisterClass procedure and and add some of my code? How to do that?

Comment: What makes you think it's spending time "registering classes"? The design of Delphi is such that registering a class *isn't* necessary. The existence of a field in the form/datamodule class and it's type is sufficient for the streaming system to locate the class type to construct.

Comment: Because I've measured the times, and it shows that register classes part took most of the time. Let me elaborate some more, maybe I was not clear enough.
I have 22 packages. Each package has (besides others) a unit with all the units in that package placed in interface section, and a procedure with simple RegisterClass(TSomeClass) for every class in that package. Every such unit from all the packages is added to main project, and a procedure that registeres all the classes in package, called before MainForm is shown.

Comment: Menu for MainForm is generated at Run Time using data stored in Database, and it is rather simple - 1 menu item per class. So clicking on MenuItem Application fetches name of the class from database and creates an instance.
And of course "Build with RunTime packages" checked.
I hope I wasn't Too elaborate :-/

Comment: Why are you calling RegisterClass so much?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using KOLDetours.pas you can intercept calls to the method and then call the original method.

You can find it here: http://code.google.com/p/asmprofiler/source/browse/trunk/SRC/KOLDetours.pas

The file contains examples of how to use it.

Comment: Just forgot. The unit uses another unit called _uAsmProfiler. You can just delete that and the few calls in the unit calling into it and it will still work fine.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question asked here, which was how to do it in Delphi itself. There's no request for a third-party library or tool to do so. You can easily do it directly in Delphi without resorting to KOL; there's no need to add that dependency. (See the comments to the original question, however.)

Answer (score 1):

To answer your specific question:

You may get the address of `Classes.RegisterClass` simply by using `@Classes.RegisterClass` as it is exposed in the interface section of Classes.pas.

The address `TRegGroup.RegisterClass` will be a bit tricky as it is not exposed in the interface section. Using the address of `Classes.RegisterClass` you could read the offset of `TRegGroup.RegisterClass` from the compiled code and then calculate the absolute address as a function of `Classes.RegisterClass`'s address. Ultimately, this will be fragile across different version of the compiler.

As an alternative, if you are willing to make a small modification to each package, you could create a unit containing a function named `RegisterClass` and ensure that the unit is included in your registration unit before `Classes.pas`. Your unit would then link against your new `RegisterClass` function which could call some notification method before calling `Classes.RegisterClass`.

As you have indicated that you are statically linking to the packages, this is all somewhat moot because you will not have an opportunity to connect whatever notification routine you devise. To solve that issue you will want to dynamically load your packages after you have created your splash screen and are prepared to pump messages for it.

Alternatively, you could modify your package registration unit to use `InitProc` to delay registration until your `TApplication` instance is created. This would give you an opportunity to create some visual means of indicating registration progress before the registration actually take place.

Answer (score 1):

In a comment you state:

> I have 22 packages. Each package has (besides others) a unit with all the units in that package placed in interface section, and a procedure with simple RegisterClass(TSomeClass) for every class in that package.

In which case the answer is obvious. Define your own function, named MyRegisterClass for instance, and call that function instead.

Comment: "With static loading the package will be loaded and its initialization sections will execute before the calling application's initialization sections are executed". And when using third party controls, which .dcp's are in requires list of my packages, their RegisterClass happens before my Application.Initialize, so I have only a partial(only of classes that call MyRegisterClass) information of progress status. In practise application is hanging while executing RegisterClass of third party controls. That is why I'd prefer intercepting - I am trying to get control of the entire registering job.

Comment: According to your comment you are wanting to intercept your own calls.

Comment: I want to intercept all calls (both mine and third party's).

Comment: OK, that wasn't clear to me. Do you have an answer to your question now though? The other answers seem to address what you asked.

Comment: Yes I have my answer now. Larsdk's answer was exactly what I was looking for. I am a newbie here, how do I reward him. I'd give him a kiss if I could :-P

Comment: You accept his answer. Give it a green tick. He gets 15 rep which is the equivalent of a kiss here! ;-)